# HTML | Description in Facebook not Changing

Tags: html, facebook

When I shared a link on the Facebook, Facebook only show the last or previous  of my Website.

New title: Kirk Niverba | Official Website

Old Title: W3Schools Web Development

[Picture Titles | Facebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3A0z.png)

Note that in the "New Title" is scriptly edited on Facebook (Inspect Element edit)

Thanks for someone will notice this =)

Comment: hello there, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I'm questioning how to "edit" the title when sharing the link on the Facebook, because Facebook is only recognizing the old title for my website. Please see the "Picture Titles" picture. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand. In order for you to do this, look specifically at this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
Which gives you some ideas about how to specify the content shown on Facebook once someone shares your web page, on their FB page.

Also for some added reference, check this links as well.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

It will give you what you need.

EDIT*** specifically, when you add it properly, these lines will give you exactly what you need alongside an image for your post/share.

```
<head>
    <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
</head>
```

Otherwise, FB uses old/current page data at random i believe. Or based on a percentage of the top 1/3 of the page(if i remember correctly).

Comment: Thank you my friend, You're my website savior, Kudos to you sir!